# How to save a secure web page with all external sources for offline view?

Tags: html, fiddler, offline-caching, offline-mode, offline-browsing

I have an ssl page that I want to mimic on my local computer while it's offline.
This page includes scripts, images and an iFrame.
I have tried all kinds of varialtion to save it through the browser, but no success.
I tried using fiddler and even have a log file with the url's visited, but I am looking for some util that would actually save the replies I'm getting back so that I will be able to replay them when I'm offline.

When I try to replay with fiddler, the page looks o.k. but the iFrame does not.
Instead of the iFrame, i get this message:

[Fiddler] The Fiddler AutoResponder is enabled, but this request did not match any of the listed rules. Because the "Unmatched requests passthrough" option on the AutoResponder tab is not enabled, this HTTP/404 response has been generated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to update your rule for the captured IFRAME such that the URL matches the URL of the URL requested by the browser on reload.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2013/01/06/how-to-use-fiddler-autoresponder-to-replay-a-fiddler-trace.aspx

Comment: I tried it, but this didn't work.
I think it's because some of the requests have a timestamp parameter, and it changes, so the right file doesn't get auto responded.
Is there a way for me to automatically delete all parameter paths from the log and just leave the base?

Comment: I think you're saying "I didn't try this, so it didn't work." There's no trivial way to edit all of the URLs at once; if there were a few, doing it manually would be simplest; if there are a lot, you could write a simple bit of JavaScript to do it. But editing blindly is just as likely to cause problems as solve them.

Comment: Definitely not! I tried your solution, but as explained by me, since there is a token that gets regenerated every few seconds, the URLs become obsolete very quickly.